# Uninitialized variables not always detected in intel visual studio 2010 (Fortran compiler 2011)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, initialization, fortran, intel-fortran

I am compiling my Fortran code in Debug mode using the flag /check:uninit, activated under properties -> Fortran -> runtime -> Check uninitialized variables.

I noticed that when I run my code sometimes execution properly stops indicating the uninitialized variable, other times it keeps running with no problems, and only stepping through my code I figure out that somewhere I have a variable  with value -6.277438562204192D+066. Why is the compiler not always able to detect uninitialized variables?

In the particular case I mentioned the undetected variable was a global variable defined in a module, I am not sure if that is a problem, maybe the compiler can only detect local uninitialized variable? If that is the case, how can I detect global uninitialized variables?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I use `valgrind` to detect uninitialized variables *at runtime*.

I'm not sure what `ifort` requires as arguments at *compile time*, but for `gfortran` you need to enable optimization as well: `-Wuninitialized -O`.

[This](http://www.fortran-2000.com/ArnaudRecipes/CompilerTricks.html#fComp_Uni) might be helpful.

EDIT: [According to Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/dont-optimize-when-using-ftrapuv-for-uninitialized-variable-detection) you must *disable* optimization when checking for uninitialized variables with `ifort`.

EDIT: I don't know how to find uninitialized variables using *Windows*, but I came along a [post from the Intel forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/362149):

> We do currently offer a limited form of run-time uninitialized
>   variable checking, though it is probably too limited to be useful.
>   Users with a license for Fortran Studio XE or Parallel Studio XE (or
>   Cluster Studio XE) can use the Static Analysis feature that does
>   whole-program correctness checking, including uninitialized variable
>   detection.  It too isn't perfect but it can be very helpful.

Maybe you have access to that tool.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention I am using Windows not Linux, and Valgrind only runs on Linux.